# Windows 8 sound theme not firing for VS2012 post build

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, audio

In windows audio settings you can set up sounds that fire for cancelled, successful and failed builds in Visual Studio, (which is jolly handy if the build is long enough to allow you to switch to another window to get on with something else). I've had this working on other versions of windows and visual studio but with **vs2012** and **Windows 8** it doesn't seem to be working. My audio setup is otherwise fine. Any idea how to troubleshoot this? Does anyone else have this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh - a reboot fixed it. I've got so used to not having to do that lately!